# Unable to run asp.net application on monodevelop

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, monodevelop

I'm on `Ubuntu 11.10`, have installed `Monodevelop-2.8.5`, on the first run, it said the `xsp2 server` was missing, I installed that.

Now, the application builds successfully, but, when I run my application, it just opens google chrome (and not my application). What is the problem?

The application output is,

```
Registering application:
    Host:          any
    Port:          any
    Virtual path:  /
    Physical path: /home/tarun/MyWebsite/MyWebsite/
xsp2
Listening on address: 127.0.0.1
Root directory: /home/tarun/MyWebsite/MyWebsite
Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
```

When I try to open, `127.0.0.1:8080` on chrome, I get the following error :

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080

But, `127.0.0.1` works just fine.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried visiting http://127.0.0.1:8080 in chrome once it opens?

Comment: Yes, it says `unable to open`, nonetheless, `127.0.0.1` opens without any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be a chrome-related problem, set `firefox` as default. Working fine now

Answer (score 0):

If you run "netstat -tlnp" from the terminal does it confirm that xsp2 really is listening on port 8080? You're looking for a line in the output something like:

```
LISTEN            8080/xsp
```

If it does seem to be listening, the next thing to try is one of the bundled sample applications. If you run /usr/lib/xsp/test/xsp then you should hopefully be able to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 from Chrome and see the sample application running.